# How to express the function with respect to only one variable?

Tags: equation-solving

We have a system of equations

```
x[t]=t^2+1
y[t]=2t+5
```

And you have to express only a function of X, ie f[x].
usually it solved as

```
y'(x)=x'(t)/y'(t)
dy/dx=(dx/dt)/(dy/dt)
```

antiderivative function and will answer

How do I get f (x) in the wolfram

Comment: `Eliminate[]` in the first case. `DSolve[]` might help for the second, but somehow you'll still have to eliminate `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) of {x[t], y[t]} it is apparent that `y` is not a function of `x` since it is multi-valued.

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{t^2 + 1, 2 t + 5},
  {t, -5, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick],
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image]

Decomposing `y` into two functions of `x`

```
soly = (2 t + 5) /. Assuming[x > 1, Solve[x == t^2 + 1, t, Reals] // Simplify]

(*  {5 - 2 Sqrt[-1 + x], 5 + 2 Sqrt[-1 + x]}  *)
```

Demonstrating that these are equivalent

```
Show[pp,
 Plot[soly, {x, 1, 26},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed]]]
```

[image]

You can define `x` as a function of `y`

```
x[y_] = t^2 + 1 /.
   Solve[y == 2 t + 5, t, Reals][[1]] //
  Simplify

(*  1 + 1/4 (-5 + y)^2  *)

x'[y]

(*  1/2 (-5 + y)  *)

Show[
 ParametricPlot[{2 t + 5, t^2 + 1},
  {t, -5, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick]],
 Plot[x[y], {y, -5, 15},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {y, x})]
```

[image]

Comment: A bit direct: `Solve[{x == t^2 + 1, y == 2 t + 5}, y, t]` (The warning thrown here is harmless.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to generate functions of y[x[t]] or what is your aim in the end? To generate responsive functions you might want to use

```
x[t_]:=t^2+1
y[t_]:=2t+5
```

so when you want to know the function y[x[t]] you can just type

```
y[x[t]]
```

and will find the correct result

```
5 + 2 (1 + t^2)
```

and can get the derivative of the functions e.g. by simply typing

```
x'[t]
```

to get

```
2t
```

as the output

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `DSolve` to get y[x], although I can't imagine that it would be better than just using `Eliminate`. Here is how you would do it:

```
eqns = {x==t[x]^2+1, y[x]==2t[x]+5};

DSolve[Join[D[eqns, x], eqns /. x->1], {t[x], y[x]}, x]
%//TeXForm
```

> {{t[x]->-Sqrt[-1+x],y[x]->5-2 Sqrt[-1+x]},{t[x]->Sqrt[-1+x],y[x]->5+2 Sqrt[-1+x]}}
>
> $\left\{\left\{t(x)\to -\sqrt{x-1},y(x)\to 5-2
>    \sqrt{x-1}\right\},\left\{t(x)\to \sqrt{x-1},y(x)\to 2
>    \sqrt{x-1}+5\right\}\right\}$

This agrees with the `Eliminate` approach suggested by @Michael E2:

```
Solve[Eliminate[eqns, t[x]], y[x]]
%//TeXForm
```

> {{y[x]->5-2 Sqrt[-1+x]},{y[x]->5+2 Sqrt[-1+x]}}
>
> $\left\{\left\{y(x)\to 5-2 \sqrt{x-1}\right\},\left\{y(x)\to
>    2 \sqrt{x-1}+5\right\}\right\}$

Where the ODE method gains utility is when the equations involve transcendental equations in a way that `Solve`/`Reduce` are unable to handle, and you want to produce an approximation function (i.e., `InterpolatingFunction`) to represent the dependence. You just replace `DSolve` with `NDSolve` and choose an appropriate range for the independent variable.